# Ninject and static constructor methods

Tags: ninject

I am using Ninject and facing the problem of having a library using a static constructor
method rather than a regular constructor:

```
  Kernel.Bind<IDocumentService>().ToMethod(
    x => CoDocumentService.Create(x.Kernel.Get<IMessage>(),x.Kernel.Get<IClientChannel>())
  ).InRequestScope();
```

The problem now is, that `IMessage` and `IClientChannel` are slightly differently implemented depending on the kind of `Service` (i.e. `IDocumentService`, `IAccountService`). I cannot distinquish the context of `IMessage` / `IClientChannel` however. I need a way to be able to know, where such an instance is going to be used.

```
this.Kernel
  .Bind<IClientChannel>()
  .To<Something>()
  .WithPropertyValue("Something",x => {"Depends on where this instance is going to be used"});
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Can you maybe provide a more complate example? Do you have multiple implementation of the `IClientChannel` interface e.g. `SimpleChannel` and `SmartChannel` and you want to pick different implementation based on whether it is inject into an `IDocumentServier` or `IAccountService`? Or have I misunderstood your problem? And what do you want to achieve with the line: `WithPropertyValue("Something"...` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ninject has simple constrained resolution: [*named bindings*](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding). Using this feature you could register  type bindings for the same service type several times:

```
kernel
    .Bind<IClientChannel>()
    .To<UniversalClientChannel>()
    .Named("IClientChannel") // named binding
    .WithPropertyValue("Number",x => 42)
```

and later resolve named instance of service directly:

```
x.Kernel.Get<IClientChannel>("IAccountService")
```

then mapping for static constructor would look like this:

```
kernel
    .Bind<IDocumentService>()
    .ToMethod(x => CoDocumentService.Create(
                       x.Kernel.Get<IMessage>(),
                       // named instance will be resolved
                       x.Kernel.Get<IClientChannel>("IClientChannel")))
    .InTransientScope();
```

**ps**: [full sample are available at gist.github](https://gist.github.com/4437787)